# bufio.NewReader always creates a new line :/

Tags: go

I use this, to collect a input and display the input then, but when I do it like this the "something" text will be displayed in a new line, but I want the text to be displayed in the same line, any ideas?

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Example")
    print("example: ")
    in := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin); 
    input, err := in.ReadString('\n');
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(input, "something")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fmt.Println()` automatically appends a newline to the end of it's output.

You could try using Printf, which takes a "format string" and a list of inputs.

An example would be:

```
func main() {
  fmt.Println("Example")
  print("example: ")
  in := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin); 
  input, err := in.ReadString('\n');
  if err != nil {
      fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
  }

  fmt.Printf("something : %s", input)
}
```

In this case, %s is a placeholder for a string type.
All the placeholders can be found in the fmt godoc: http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/

Also if the input itself has a newline at the end, you can use `Trim` from the package `strings` to pull off the \n character.

Comment: Is it possible to use this with string? "fmt.Printf(string : %s, input)" doesn't work :(

Comment: The first argument has to be of type string (e.g: enclosed in double quotes), all subsequent arguments have to match the placeholders types in order.  

It will print out the first string as-is, replacing the placeholders as necessary.


Another example would be:  
`fmt.Printf("The int is: %d, the string is %s", 3, "a string.")`
(%d appplies to type int, %s applies to string)

Answer (score 3):

Trim the newline from `input`. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Example")
    print("example: ")
    in := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    input, err := in.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(strings.TrimRight(input, "\n"), "something")
}
```

Input/Output:

```
Example
example: some input
some input something
```

Comment: Nice, but I get the following error: "panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range"

Comment: Works for me. Did you get an error? If `err` is non-nil and `input` is empty, you should should call `os.Exit(1)` or `panic(err)` or `return` or at least put the second `fmt.Println()` in the else block.

Comment: If you run the revised version with the return statement, what error do you get?

Answer (score 2):

On windows (not sure if that is relevant) none of the previous answers worked for me. So here's the resolution I found on: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/hWoESdeZ398/qDbTogJhj88J which links to https://play.golang.org/p/_9N_RwmBvd

The basic idea is that rather than using `strings.TrimRight(input, "\n")` you would include a `\r` character, like `strings.TrimRight(input, "\r\n")`
This fixes the OPs issue.

OP code with fixed input stripping!

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Example")
    print("example: ")
    in := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin); 
    input, err := in.ReadString('\n');
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(strings.TrimRight(input, "\r\n"), "something")
}
```

PS: Sorry for the necro I'm just hoping to save someone from wasting 20 minutes googling!